# SuiteCRM Database Scheduler

Tags: php, sugarcrm, suitecrm

I installed SuiteCRM and while trying to run the code below for for the Scheduler...

**`php.exe -f cron.php`**

I get the error:

> Call to undefined function mysqli_connect()

Can anyone help?

Comment: Does SuiteCRM work if you go to the actual site?

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the mysqli PHP extension is installed? try viewing the phpinfo, either from a php `phpifno();` or from the command line `php -i`.

If this wasn't installed it would effect the whole installation rather than just the scheduler.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your command line PHP ( PHP CLI ) refers to seperte location than your PHP.

Get path of php.ini for your command line and then uncomment this line.

extension=mysqli

Answer (score 0):

The cron.php is run from the scheduler, but sometimes I have to run the code to make sure is working  properly.

> php cron.php all -F -vvv

where

- the “all” command will execute all the tasks
- The “-F” option forces all the tasks to be executed.
- The “-vvv” option sets the output verbosity level to maximum.

If I need to edit my web server user's crontab file, I use this command:

> sudo crontab -e -u username

If I need to find out the username the cron job is running on, I use the browser

> domain.com/get_current_user.php

assuming I already created the get_current_user.php file.